# How to update data row in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to get value from the database and showing to the datatables with a condition, and if I change input form value (This input value is a condition for query so if i change the value the data in the datatable will change) but when i use on change it's work but when i try twice to change value they say i reinitialise, any suggestion to make it right?

I already try to that code, it's work but if i change the value again it's error says 'DataTables warning: table id=dataTr - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

```
var asset = $('#formasset').find('input[name="ckdasset"]').val();
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#ckdasset').on('change',function(){
      var dataTable = $('#dataTr').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "ajax":{
          url :"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Logged/get_detail_data/"+kode_asset_new+", 
          type: "post",  // method  , by default get
          error: function(){  // error handling
            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
            $("#dataTr").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

          }
        }
      } );
    });
        } );
```

Comment: Did you try the Resolution provided in the page you linked to ? It explains it quite well and how to fix it. https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, You're initializing the datatable again instead of reset/redraw.

```
 var asset = $('#formasset').find('input[name="ckdasset"]').val();
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var dataTable = $('#dataTr').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Logged/get_detail_data/" + kode_asset_new + ", 
                  type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                        error: function () {  // error handling
                            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                            $("#dataTr").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display", "none");

                        }
                    }
                });
                $('#ckdasset').on('change', function () {
                    var Dt = $('#dataTr').DataTable();
                    Dt.fnDraw();
                });
            });
```